# Add static html block in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, include

I have a block of static html I'm using in several places in different models and views. It would be great to have this only exist in one file I can include in many places, so that I don't have to change 15 files when I want to edit it.

However, it's frustratingly difficult for me to understand how this is done in CakePHP. I've read the Views documentation many times and I am drawing a blank.

How do I put a block of code here:

```
/View/Common/colors.ctp
```

and then insert it in other views:

```
/View/People/view.ctp
/View/Cars/view.ctp
...
```

?

It seems like something that ought to be very simple, so I'm probably missing something obvious and I'm sure this question looks dumb. I appreciate a swift kick in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can use elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)

Move colors.ctp in View/Elements

Inside View/People/view.ctp, you can use

```
echo $this->element('colors');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ctp file is just php, so you can just `include` your file, remembering that the location will be relative to webroot.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be something crazy simple. This works, thanks. Will accept when I can.

Comment: You can do this, but the point to view objects in Cake is that they are themeable. Now if you're not using a theme and have no plan to, this will work fine. But if you think you might need a theme (desktop vs mobile, etc) using $this->element('colors') will use the ctp file from the current theme that is in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is one simple solution:

Step 1: Create colors.ctp in /View/Elements/colors.ctp and put code of /View/Common/colors.ctp in /View/Elements/colors.ctp

Step 2: Open /View/Common/colors.ctp and remove all the content from the file and put below code. `<?php echo $this->element('colors');?>`

Step 3: Open /View/People/view.ctp and /View/Cars/view.ctp and so on...Now put below code to include colors.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->element('colors'); ?>
```

Now /View/Elements/colors.ctp is element file which has static content and you can include /View/Elements/colors.ctp in views easily.

Hope it will help you!